# Fixa cabeçalho de relatório no Report Server

Tags: reporting-services

Qual a propriedade para que o cabeçalho em um relatório feito no report server seja repetida em todas as páginas?

Como mostrado na imagem abaixo quero que a linha em amarelo seja repetida em todas as outras páginas.

Já tentei usa  `FixedRowHeaders` e o `RepeatRowHeaders`, mas não deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - No programa, mais embaixo da tela que você está de Design ou Criar é pra ter uma janela **Grupo de Colunas** ou **Columns Groups**. No canto tem uma seta, clique sobre ela e vai em **Modo Avançado**.

2 - Selecione toda a linha que quer repetir em todas as páginas, depois clique em **static** na janela que está embaixo.

3 - Aperte **F4** para abrir as propriedades.

4 - Sete a propriedade **KeepWithGroup** como **After**.

5 - Depois sete **RepeatOnNewPage** como **true**.

Caso queira a linha congelada enquanto rola o relatório sete **FixedData** como **true**.

Comment: Cara, vlw deu certo